# Can't seem to catch exceptions using Js2Py in a Python project

Tags: javascript, python

I am using [Js2Py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py) to execute a block of Javascript code in my Python module. For testing, I specifically made a syntax error to check. I put the whole thing in a try-except block, but it still seems to raise an exception. It looks like this:

```
try:
    self.validator_function_compiled = js2py.eval_js("function( value ) { if ( value.length > 10) { return false; } return true; }")
except Exception as e:
    pass
```

When I run this code, I still get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: consol is not defined
```

Why is this?

Comment: This looks like a typical javascript error from incorrectly typing console. Are you sure this is the only javascript that you're testing?

Comment: Yep, thats all I am doing.